# Adding "Compare with Field" operation to JQuery QueryBuilder

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-builder

Using [jQuery QueryBuilder](http://querybuilder.js.org/index.html) I want to modify the value input based on the selected "compare with" operations to provide a list of the fields in the queryBuilder.

Operations for (for example) "less_than_other_column" are added and, when selected, should update the Rule input field to provide a select box containing the entries for each of the QueryBuilder fields. I can add the operation entries at run time, but I am not sure how to manipulate the $(queryBuilder) Rule entry to provide the value input as a selection of the querybuilder fields when a compare_with type operation is selected.

What events and templates in the QueryBuilder system should I look at?

Hoping some combination of handlers from http://querybuilder.js.org/dev/events.html will help.

Comment: From http://querybuilder.js.org/dev/events.html, I'm hoping that this can be modified by the trigger:  afterUpdateRuleOperator.queryBuilder and changer: getRuleInput.queryBuilder.filter